# How do I start an android application automatically when I turn on the TV?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, mobile

I added these permissions to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and I added the **BootReceiver** to the Manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.portlmedia.streets.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:directBootAware="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And I created the  **BootReceiver** in my project:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

My question, if you can help me is how do I test this using the emulator in android studio?

I put a breakpoint in the onReceive method, but when I start the application it doesn't hit it
I tried also With Cold Reboot, but nothing, and I want to test if indeed works, or maybe is a problem in my code?

Comment: "How do I start the android application automatically when I turn on the TV?" -- at best, your code is for running your app when the Android TV device boots. That may not be related to when you turn on your TV. Also note that you cannot start an activity from the background on modern versions of Android, such as from an on-boot `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @CommonsWare so is there any way i can get this behavior?

Comment: I do not know precisely what "this behavior" is or why users would want it. You might consider explaining in greater detail what the user experience is that you are trying to achieve. In the absence of those details, it sounds like you want to replace the Android TV launcher.

Comment: @CommonsWare We want to prioritize that when a screen turns off/powered off etc...the TV when turned on goes directly into the app/wrapper.

Comment: I do not know that an Android TV device necessarily knows when the TV is turned on or off. It *definitely* will require you to test with hardware, as the emulator does not emulate a TV plus an Android TV device. Since the behavior of the hardware may vary, I recommend that you obtain several Android TV devices from a range of manufacturers. Then, you can see if features like [this one](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware#powerOff) will address your concerns.

Comment: As I guess you only want to test this functionality with emulator. Put one log inside `onReceive` method and when your emulator open/restart/reboot `onReceive` will trigger in `BroadcastReceiver`. Hope you find it helpful. Sometimes it takes some time to trigger `onReceive` after open/restart/reboot emulator. As @CommonsWare mentioned latest API devices cannot start activity from the background you need to take overlay permission for latest API devices.

Comment: Yeah, similar problems have been faced and rectified by the following steps: Kindly ensure the boot receiver receives the onReceive method. If it receives first, add android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW and get permission granted by the user or using the adb. If it's not working again, then add a foreground service and start the activity from the service. I will add the code in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Manifest code

Add permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Inside the application class

```
         <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />  
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

       <service
            android:name=".AppStartService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Step 2: Get the Overlay permission granted by the user or

```
adb shell pm grant com.example.appstart android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

Step 3: BootReceiver

```
class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: boot received ${intent?.action}")
        val serviceIntent = Intent(context, AppStartService::class.java)
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "BootReceiver"
    }
}
```

Step 4 : Service code

```
class AppStartService: Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startForeground(1, createNotification())

        GlobalScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                try {
                    val intent = Intent(this@AppStartService, MainActivity::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    startActivity(intent)
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: ", ex)
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID,
            "${getString(R.string.app_name)} Service",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        val manager = getSystemService(
            NotificationManager::class.java
        )
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)

        return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("${getString(R.string.app_name)} Service")
            .setSilent(true)
            .setContentText("Please restart this device if this service is not running")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .build()
    }


    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "AppStartService"
        private const val CHANNEL_ID = "app-start-service"
    }

}
```

In my case, BootReceiver class receives boot completed action. So, Working for me! Ensure boot complete action works on particular device.